# `Conda` packaging: Building package with `conda-forge` as my priority channel, but will users get the same packages when installing

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, conda-forge

I am creating a python package using `conda` package manager and `conda-forge` dependencies. I need to use some dependencies from `conda-forge`, so according to `conda-forge` [documentation](https://conda-forge.org/docs/user/tipsandtricks.html), I created a `.condarc` file and set the following settings:

```
channel_priority: strict
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
```

So now when the package is building, it will look at `conda-forge` packages first.

My question was about users installing the package. So if a user installed my package,
would they automatically receive all of the `conda-forge` dependencies, or would it depend on their local machine's channel priority, etc?

In other words, say I build the package--called `mypack`--using `gdal` from `conda-forge`. So when a user enters `conda install -c conda-forge mypack` to install the package, will the user get the `gdal` dependency from `conda-forge` too, or will he/she get it from whatever their channel priority determines?

Seems like the package should stick with the same source as it was built with. But I wanted to confirm this.

Comment: The dependencies will be determined by the channel order of the user. I don't think you can control that.

Comment: @cel , yeah see that is what I was worried about. I need to pin the `gdal` version and the channel of that version too. Otherwise I guess I just have to pin like the exact build string for each version, etc.

Comment: If you pin the build string, and the user doesn't have the appropriate channel, they will get solver errors when they try to install your package. My suggestion would be in your installation documentation, specify the `gdal` package as well: `conda install -c conda-forge mypack gdal` or `conda install mypack conda-forge::gdal`